# How to remove user id on url drupal 9

Tags: drupal

http://localhost/drupal-9.3.3/user/372#myaccount

How to remove user id on URL . Please suggest how to change these type security isssue.

Comment: Having the user id on the URL is not, by itself, a security issue (per se)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the url structure to remove ids, use pathauto https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto

You can choose to have an url structure for user profiles that can be generated from any user field.

Answer (score -2):

Someone told me that everything you write on the front end or in your main folder is always just basically a suggestion a.k.a. not secure.

Good ways to secure site:

1. Authenticate users using backend like firebase read/write permissions
2. Use randomized urls / keys (which firebase also does)
3. Also catch exceptions and deal with them, perferably at the the place where that function is created, not when it is executed:

Example

yes:
`function() => {` 
`// do something`
`//catch error`
`}`
`function();` // call function;

No:
`function().then(error => {  //do something})`

Comment: how does your answer remove the user id from the URL?

Comment: The backend takes care of the security, so even if someone goes to that url, they won't be able to authenticate. You can just manually change the url.